# Focus abstraction

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus

`UserControl` with buttons (some of them are disabled) is nested inside other `UserControl`. There are several of such displayed in the window at once.

Now I need to set focus to first enabled button of nested `UserControl`, while the logic to choose focus will run on the level of window (e.g. when window will enable certain `UserControl`).

I need to be able to pass that focus request (via properties?) through several ViewModels and finally trigger it in the View of nested `UserControl`.

Ho can I **abstract focus request**? E.g. I want to be able to tell "set focus to this high level UserControl" and that should somehow *automatically* go through nested `UserControl` and its buttons, because only button **is** the element what **can** receive focus.

Pseudo-code:

```
// in window
UserControlA.Focus();

// should in fact set focus to 4th button of nested user control
UserControlA.UserControlB.ButtonD.Focus();

// because of data templates it is actually more like this
var nested = UserControlA.ContentControl.Content as UserControlB;
var firstEnabledButton = nested.ItemsControl[3] as Button;
firstEnabledButton.SetFocus();

// and because of MVVM it may be as simple as
ViewModelA.IsFocused = true;
// but then A should run
ViewModelB.IsFocused = true;
// and then B should set property of button ViewModel
Buttons.First(o => o.IsEnabled).IsFocused = true.
// and then this has to be somehow used by the view (UserControlB) to set focus...
```

Problem is not with how to set focus in MVVM, this [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226116/1997232) somehow (with triggers it needs ugly workaround where property is first set to `false`). My problem is how to pass that request ("and then ..., and then ..., and then..." in example above).

Any ideas?

---

I am looking for a simple and intuitive xaml solution with the most reusability. I don't want to spam every ViewModel and views with `...IsFocused` properties and bindings.

I can use some *side effect* to my advantage, e.g. consider this behavior

```
public static bool GetFocusWhenEnabled(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(FocusWhenEnabledProperty);
public static void SetFocusWhenEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(FocusWhenEnabledProperty, value);

public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusWhenEnabledProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusWhenEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
    {
        var element = d as UIElement;
        if (element == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Only used with UIElement");
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            element.IsEnabledChanged += FocusWhenEnabled_IsEnabledChanged;
        else
            element.IsEnabledChanged -= FocusWhenEnabled_IsEnabledChanged;
    }));

static void FocusWhenEnabled_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
    if (element.IsEnabled)
        element.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => element.Focus()); // invoke is a must
}
```

which can be used to *automatically* focus enabled element. This require some `IsEnabled` logic **in addition** and will easily stop working in some complicated scenarios (where enabling should not cause the focusing).

---

I am thinking if I can add some attached property to **pass focus requests** all the way through xaml (using only xaml) when attempting to set focus to container, which is not focusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider using the [`FrameworkElement.MoveFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.movefocus(v=vs.110).aspx) method together with `FocusNavigationDirection.Next` - this should in general give you the expected result, i.e. give focus to the first encountered control which can receive keyboard focus. In particular that means that non-focusable controls, disabled controls, and controls that cannot receive keyboard focus (such as `ItemsControl`, `UserControl` etc.) will be omitted. The only catch here is that the controls will be traversed in **tab order**, but unless you're messing around with that it should traverse the visual tree in depth-first pre-order manner. So this code:

```
UserControlA.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

should give focus to `UserControlA.UserControlB.ButtonD` if it is the first keyboard-focusable and enabled descendant of `UserControlA`.

In terms of dismissing the necessity to use code-behind what I'd do is the following. First of all I'd drop using view-model properties to control focus. Moving focus seems to me a lot more like request-based concept rather than state-based, so I'd use events (e.g. `FocusRequested`) instead. To make it reusable I'd create a one-event interface (e.g. `IRequestFocus`). The final touch would be to create a behavior that would automatically inspect if `DataContext` of the attached object implements `IRequestFocus` and call `MoveFocus` each time the `FocusRequested` event is raised.

With such setup all you'd need to do is to implement `IRequestFocus` in `ViewModelA`, and attach the behavior to `UserControlA`. Then simply raising the `FocusRequested` in `ViewModelA` would result in moving focus to `UserControlA.UserControlB.ButtonD`.

Comment: Using `MoveFocus` is a great idea, thanks. It can be used on any container to **pass** the focus into (or further) and that alone solves my current issue perfectly, as I don't have to deal with `IsFocused` in ViewModel's anymore, only invoke that in the view and it will automatically set the focus *somewhere*. Though as *usual* this require [a trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13859473/1997232) to `Invoke` with `DispatcherPriority.Render` priority. As for *abstraction* part (deal with focus manually) your suggestions are pretty reasonable, I'll surely use them if that become a requirement.

Comment: I guess it depends on when you move the focus - I created a simple test project where the focus was moved upon button click and it worked fine without the `Dispatcher`. Good catch though.