# BackgroundWorker to read database and update GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am trying to keep my indeterminate `ProgressBar` animation running smoothly as I query database and updating `DataGrid` in **`DoWork`** in **`BackgroundWorker`**. I understand that I cannot update UIThread in **`DoWork`**, so I use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to access `DataGrid`, yet I still receive the owned-by-another-thread exception.

> Question 1
>
> Why is this happening? DoWork should be on
>   BackgroundWorker's thread owned by UIThread, and Dispatcher should
>   allow my DoWork to access my GUI.

Looking further into BackgroundWorker suggest UI operation should be handled in **`ProgressChanged()`**. But if I move all database/GUI operation to **`ProgressChanged()`** and put a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` on **`DoWork()`** to emulate something to work on to lend enough time for **`ProgressChanged()`** to run, the GUI is not being updated, although the `ProgressBar` continue its indeterminate smooth animation.

> Question 2
>
> I called a Thread.Sleep(5000) on BackgroundWorker thread.
>   ProgressChanged() should spend 5 seconds querying database and
>   updating GUI. Why not?

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True" 
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
          Height="500" MaxHeight="500" />

<ProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" Height="20" Width="400"
             IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Visible" />

<Button x:Name="mySearch" Click="btnSearch_Click">Search</Button>
```

**C#**

```
private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

private void btnSearch_Click(object sendoer, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    bgw.DoWork += DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += BGW_RunWorkerCompleted;

    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Thread.Sleep(5000);
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + MyTableName, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        myDataGrid.Items.Add(new
                        {
                            Id = rdr.GetInt32(0),
                            Name = rdr.GetString(1).ToString(),
                        });
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // Paste code from DoWork and uncomment Thread.Sleep(5000)
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Exception is thrown in Dispatcher when GUI (i.e. DataGrid) gets updated. If operation is in DoWork(), I get 'the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' exception.

Comment: Please refer to my answer.

Comment: What object owns the `Dispatcher` you're using? And is it associated with the same thread that `myDataGrid` is? You may try it, and it is good practice, to use the dispatcher associated with the object you're trying to access. In your case that would be `myDataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`.

Comment: Instead of `BeginInvoke` use `Invoke` in your `DoWork` method. This way it will trigger the action on a UI Thread. However I would probably cache the results to a 100 results and then call the UI thread, as you are already using `Virtualization`.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, and why this question is being discouraged to being asked? I find no similar duplicate, I believe I worded my question properly in a way to seek understanding instead of asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of items in your `DoWork` event handler and then set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to this one in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler once you are done fetching the data on a background thread:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sendoer, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgw.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
    bgw.DoWork += DoWork;
    bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += BGW_RunWorkerCompleted;

    myProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<object> results = new List<object>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + MyTableName, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    results.Add(new
                    {
                        Id = rdr.GetInt32(0),
                        Name = rdr.GetString(1).ToString(),
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    e.Result = results;
}

private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result as List<object>;
    myProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

You need to call the `ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorker` for any progress to be reported but it is pretty meaningless to report progress from a database retrieval operation since you have no clue about the actual progress anyway. You'd better just use an indeterminate `ProgressBar` and show it when you start the operation and hiding it when the operation has completed as demonstrated in the sample code above.

And `Thread.Sleep` will block the current thread. If you block the UI thread, your UI, including your ProgressBar, cannot be updated so you don't want to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution but I still like to understand my question. My progressbar is already indeterminate, but the animation freeze even to my understanding is running on a different thread

Comment: The delegate that you pass to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is always executed on the dispatcher thread. So if you call BeginInvoke in a tight loop, the UI thread will freeze.

Comment: I replicate your code line-by-line, but yet the indeterminate ProgressBar animation freeze. I guess updating ItemsSource in RunWorkerCompleted() would freeze the UI.

Comment: Also using ItemsSource instead of SqlDataReader adding DataGrid line-by-line increase memory usage of up to 30% and correspondingly slower loading time. Hence I still like to understand the questions so I can understand how to approach

Comment: "Also using ItemsSource instead of SqlDataReader...". No. Where do you think the items that you see in the DataGrid are stored when you add them to the Items collection? Setting the ItemsSource to an IEnumerable certainly has no impact on performance compared to adding items directly to the Items property. You should prefer the former approach. In fact, it is required if you want to be able to edit the items. And if you freeze when you set the ItemsSource property, you have probably disabled the UI virtualization somehow.