# BackgroundWorker for fetching DataBase and put it in a DataGrid with dynamically added Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mysqldatareader

I read this question: [BackgroundWorker to read database and update GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409234/backgroundworker-to-read-database-and-update-gui)

And thinks, that this is a good way to solve this problem.
The only thing is, that I create my Columns dynamically.

I read schemaInfo from DataBase to get the ColumnNames and create a DataGridColumn foreach Column in DataBase.

Now i want to do this with a BackgroundWorker, but u can't update the UI with a BackgroundWorker.

For now (without BackgroundWorker) I have 2 Methods to get the DataBase values.

To load the columns:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            using (DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable())
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow col in schema.Rows)
                                {
                                    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();

                                    string columnstring = col.Field<String>("ColumnName");
                                    comboFilter.Items.Add(UppercaseFirst(columnstring));

                                    column.Binding = new Binding(col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
                                    column.Header = UppercaseFirst(col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
                                    column.IsReadOnly = true;

                                    Style textStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
                                    textStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
                                    column.ElementStyle = textStyle;

                                    dataGridPrivatecustomers.Columns.Add(column);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

To load values

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", privateCustomerTablename), connection))
                        {
                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                                dataGridPrivatecustomers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                            }
                        }
```

So I tried to make both in one and struggled at creating the result List for the DataGrad's ItemSource:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            using (DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable())
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
                                {
                                    results.Add(new
                                    {

                                    });
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The thing is, that I need to know how I can put the ColumnName + Value in the result List.

In the linked question he did 
`Id = rdr.GetInt32(0),`

But i can't do `row.Field<String>("ColumnName") = reader[i].ToString()`
The code also don't know how much Columns to add so i guess i need another for or foreach loop ? And how I can set the ColumnName ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that some people want to know this too because (for me) it looks really tricky for beginning Developers who wan't Columns and Values from DataBase to show in a DataGrid with a BackgroundWorker.

So i will show you, how I solved my question.

First I created a List to store all ColumnNames.

```
private List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
```

After that I edited the worker_DoWork Event as follows:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string))
        {
            if (OpenConnection(connection))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", privateCustomerTablename);
                    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        using (DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
                        {
                            columnList.Clear();
                            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
                            {
                                columnList.Add(row.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, connection))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                            e.Result = dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

First you can see i made a DataReader to read the DataBase schema and store it in a DataTable so I can loop it trough a foreach loop. In this Loop I add each Item from the schemaTable to my List so the List contains all ColumnNames of the selected DataBase Table.

After that I created a DataAdapter and store the content to another DataTable. And i pass this DataTable via `e.Result = dt` to the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted Event`. Now I want to access this data in my `worker_RunWorkerCompleted Event`.

```
        private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in columnList)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();

            column.Binding = new Binding(item);
            column.Header = UppercaseFirst(item);
            column.IsReadOnly = true;

            dataGridPrivatecustomers.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        DataTable dt = e.Result as DataTable;
        dataGridPrivatecustomers.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

I loop all items in my columnList and create a DataGridTextColumn for each item in this list and add it to my DataGrid.

After that all Columns are added into my DataGrid and I set the ItemsSource of my DataGrid to the DataTable i passed from `worker_DoWork` to `worker_RunWorkerCompleted`.